# Why does the prompt "You have unspent skill points" constantly pop up in Dying Light?

Tags: dying-light

Every few minutes, the prompt "You have unspent skill points" pops up, even though I have no unspent skill points. When I press <kbd>U</kbd> I see my 4 skill trees, and they all have `Points: 0` below them.

Is there some other kind of skill point that can be spent that I don't know about, or is this a bug? I couldn't find anything by Googling the issue.

---

I'm running the latest version of Dying Light from Steam.

Comment: I would just assume it's a bug, if you truly have no points left. Maybe try to spend a point in each tree and see if it lets you? Also, it's possible that goes away after you earn a point and spend it.

Comment: @DangerZone I have now played for probably 10 hours since I made this question, and gained a dozen levels in each tree. I'm still being spammed by the prompt every couple of minutes :(

Comment: It's gotta just be some annoying bug... And I'm assuming it won't let you spend some random "free point" in any tree?

Comment: Like @DangerZone said, probably just a bug. Maybe report it to them on steam and a dev might get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it could be if you own the following but have gone back to the main game it could be telling you about the points in your buggy skill tree? This happened to me but by going and spending the points in the following it fixed it for me.